# Screen record with sound - AVFoundation? Desktop Mac

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

I was trying to create two things. Both for desktop mac. Both which involve recording screen/audio.

In first thing, which is my main priority right now, I am making a song identifier. The second thing, is a screen capture (with audio) thing.

I was thinking of using `AVFoundation`. I don't see any sound recording capabilities though, just playing - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067

Is it possbile to record system audio somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for Mac or iOS?

Comment: Thanks for asking @Lucas I'll clarify, it's for desktop mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this document in the past to figure out the live screen recording part. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1740/_index.html

You'll probably also find the code snipped in the [AVCaptureSession overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/) useful.

The gist of it is that AVCaptureSession is the object that controls all your inputs and outputs for the given capture session. In this case it would be AVCaptureScreenInput and I believe for audio you want AVCaptureDeviceInput of type audio. There is a way to get the list of all the [available devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVCaptureDevice/devicesWithMediaType:) for a AVCaptureDevice of a specific type. Then you add AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to your session output.

I know that's a little high level, but that technical Q&A as well as looking into getting particular input types should help.

Comment: Dear Lucas thank you very much for this direction I'll start clawing at it. If you do come across any complete code examples I would super appreciate the share. I'm not too much of a C guy, I do mostly porting via ctypes. :) That AVCaptureSession is a great starting point, thank you!

Comment: Fair enough, I had a project at one point that displayed in a gui the available video and audio inputs and created a video output from that. I wish I would have kept that or posted it somewhere. I'll consider posting it if I get a chance.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your thought Lucas! :) thank you!

Comment: @Noitidart Out of curiousity, were you doing this project in Swift or Obj-C?

Comment: Objective-c and off the main thread. :) But if I have to I can run on main thread. It's last resort though as I cannot dispatch to the mainthread, its an issue in the app i'm writing addon for.